# Recursive higher order function type in Scala 3

Tags: scala, higher-order-functions, scala-3, higher-order-types

I want to define a type for a function that does something and then returns another function of the same type [can be itself]. The obvious idea didn't work ("Illegal cyclic type reference" error):

```
type Behavior[S] = S => Behavior[S]
```

Is there something obvious that I am missing here? Also I do not understand how to express an idea of "function returning itself".

Comment: Isn't this unsound? How will this type check? The unification would never terminate. You can define a type like this `type Behavior[S, K <: Behavior[S, _]] = S => K` but you can't actually use it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Short answer

```
case class Behavior[S](step: S => Behavior[S])
```

## Long answer (short version)

[Terminal F-Coalgebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-coalgebra#Examples) are pretty cool.

## Long answer

*Warning: lots of barbed wire & co-bananas, or something...*

Ok, so, suppose that you have the concept of a functor `F` that captures what it means that your behavior "does something". In most libraries is something like this:

```
trait Functor[F[_]]:
  def map[A, B](fa: F[A])(f: A => B): F[B]
```

An `F`-coalgebra `A` is essentially just a function from `A` to `F[A]`:

```
trait FCoalg[F[_]: Functor, A]:
  def apply(a: A): F[A]
```

Now, a *terminal* `F`-coalgebra `T` is an `F`-coalgebra which additionally has a property that from every other `F`-coalgebra `A` there is a mediating morphism `A => T` (such that everything commutes, blah blah):

```
trait TerminalFCoalg[F[_]: Functor, T] extends FCoalg[F, T]:
  def mediate[A](coalg: FCoalg[F, A]): A => T
```

Can we implement it for arbitrary `F`? It turns out we can:

```
case class TerminalFCoalgCarrier[F[_]: Functor](
  step: () => F[TerminalFCoalgCarrier[F]]
)

given tfcImpl[F[_]: Functor]: TerminalFCoalg[F, TerminalFCoalgCarrier[F]] with
  def apply(a: TerminalFCoalgCarrier[F]): F[TerminalFCoalgCarrier[F]] = a.step()
  def mediate[A](coalg: FCoalg[F, A]): A => TerminalFCoalgCarrier[F] = a =>
    TerminalFCoalgCarrier(() => summon[Functor[F]].map(coalg(a))(mediate(coalg)))
```

For the sake of a concrete example, let's see what that contraption does for the simplest imaginable functor `Option`:

```
given Functor[Option] with
  def map[A, B](fa: Option[A])(f: A => B): Option[B] = fa.map(f)

type ConaturalNumber = TerminalFCoalgCarrier[Option]
```

It turns out that the terminal `F`-coalgebra for `Option` are the so-called *conatural numbers*. These are basically the natural numbers, plus countable infinity. These things are nicely suitable for representing lengths of potentially infinite "clicking" processes.

Let's try it on a finite behavior:

```
enum WelshCounting:
  case Eeny
  case Meeny
  case Miny
  case Moe

object WelshCountingOptionCoalg extends FCoalg[Option, WelshCounting]:
  def apply(w: WelshCounting): Option[WelshCounting] =
    import WelshCounting._
    w match
      case Eeny => None
      case Meeny => Some(Eeny)
      case Miny => Some(Meeny)
      case Moe => Some(Miny)

val welshMediatingMorphism =
  summon[TerminalFCoalg[Option, TerminalFCoalgCarrier[Option]]]
  .mediate(WelshCountingOptionCoalg)
```

Now, the above machinery automatically gives us a universal way to translate those counting words into conatural numbers. Let's add a helper method for describing conatural numbers (approximately):

```
def describe(c: ConaturalNumber): String =
  var counter = 0
  var curr = c
  while true do
    curr.step() match
      case None => return s"${counter}"
      case Some(next) =>
        if counter > 42 then
          return "probably infinite"
        else {
          counter += 1
          curr = next
        }
  throw new Error("We have counted to infinity, yay! :D")
```

What does it show for the Welsh counting words?

```
@main def demo(): Unit =
  for w <- WelshCounting.values do
    val conat = welshMediatingMorphism(w)
    println(s"${w} -> ${describe(conat)}")

// Eeny -> 0
// Meeny -> 1
// Miny -> 2
// Moe -> 3
```

Ok, that's neat. Let's try an infinitely clicking process with just one state that is successor of itself:

```
object LoopForever extends FCoalg[Option, Unit]:
  def apply(u: Unit) = Some(())

val loopForeverMediatingMorphism =
  summon[TerminalFCoalg[Option, TerminalFCoalgCarrier[Option]]]
    .mediate(LoopForever)
```

How would it now describe the single state `()`?

```
println(s"${()} -> ${describe(loopForeverMediatingMorphism(()))}")
// () -> probably infinite
```

Seems to work.

---

Full code:

```
trait Functor[F[_]]:
  def map[A, B](fa: F[A])(f: A => B): F[B]

trait FCoalg[F[_]: Functor, A]:
  def apply(a: A): F[A]

trait TerminalFCoalg[F[_]: Functor, T] extends FCoalg[F, T]:
  def mediate[A](coalg: FCoalg[F, A]): A => T

case class TerminalFCoalgCarrier[F[_]: Functor](
  step: () => F[TerminalFCoalgCarrier[F]]
)

given tfcImpl[F[_]: Functor]: TerminalFCoalg[F, TerminalFCoalgCarrier[F]] with
  def apply(a: TerminalFCoalgCarrier[F]): F[TerminalFCoalgCarrier[F]] = a.step()
  def mediate[A](coalg: FCoalg[F, A]): A => TerminalFCoalgCarrier[F] = a =>
    TerminalFCoalgCarrier(() => summon[Functor[F]].map(coalg(a))(mediate(coalg)))

given Functor[Option] with
  def map[A, B](fa: Option[A])(f: A => B): Option[B] = fa.map(f)

type ConaturalNumber = TerminalFCoalgCarrier[Option]

def describe(c: ConaturalNumber): String =
  var counter = 0
  var curr = c
  while true do
    curr.step() match
      case None => return s"${counter}"
      case Some(next) =>
        if counter > 42 then
          return "probably infinite"
        else {
          counter += 1
          curr = next
        }
  throw new Error("We cannot count to infinity :(")

enum WelshCounting:
  case Eeny
  case Meeny
  case Miny
  case Moe

object WelshCountingOptionCoalg extends FCoalg[Option, WelshCounting]:
  def apply(w: WelshCounting): Option[WelshCounting] =
    import WelshCounting._
    w match
      case Eeny => None
      case Meeny => Some(Eeny)
      case Miny => Some(Meeny)
      case Moe => Some(Miny)

val welshMediatingMorphism =
  summon[TerminalFCoalg[Option, TerminalFCoalgCarrier[Option]]]
    .mediate(WelshCountingOptionCoalg)

object LoopForever extends FCoalg[Option, Unit]:
  def apply(u: Unit) = Some(())

val loopForeverMediatingMorphism =
  summon[TerminalFCoalg[Option, TerminalFCoalgCarrier[Option]]]
    .mediate(LoopForever)

@main def demo(): Unit =
  for w <- WelshCounting.values do
    val conat = welshMediatingMorphism(w)
    println(s"${w} -> ${describe(conat)}")

  println(s"${()} -> ${describe(loopForeverMediatingMorphism(()))}")
```